# Importing package within that package doesn't work in 2.7.15rc1 but does in 2.7.15

Tags: python, import, package, circular-dependency

I'm making a website using python Flask(no knowledge of flask needed to answer question). On my PC, I'm running python 2.7.15 and the app works fine. When I move it onto my Ubuntu webserver with python 2.7.15rc1, it stops working. I'm using somewhat circular imports, but I've made sure it all works(I can handle the circular imports just fine). This is the traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/OpenNoteFlask/opennoteflask.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
     from OpenNoteFlask import app as application
   File "/var/www/OpenNoteFlask/OpenNoteFlask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from OpenNoteFlask import create_app
   File "/var/www/OpenNoteFlask/OpenNoteFlask/OpenNoteFlask/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
     from OpenNoteFlask.config import Config
 ImportError: No module named config
```

This is my file strucure:

```
(The numbers in parenthesis are to distinguish the files and folders here.
They do not appear in the actual names of the files and folders)

OpenNoteFlask (1)
    __init__.py (1)
    OpenNoteFlask (2)
        __init__.py (2)
        config.py
```

Inside `__init__.py (1)` I have `from OpenNoteFlask import create_app` (and it finds the import successfuly).

Inside `__init__.py (2)` I have `from OpenNoteFlask.config import Config` (and it doesn't find the import). Again, this only happens on my Ubuntu webserver and not on my PC.

I already tried:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path to parent of OpenNoteFlask (2)")
from OpenNoteFlask.config import Config
```

But that doesn't change anything.

To reiterate, I have package `OpenNoteFlask`, where I have an `__init__.py` file that imports that same `OpenNoteFlask` package's `config.py` module, but it fails to find that module. This is only happening on my Ubuntu webserver which runs python 2.7.15rc1, but works fine on my PC which is running python 2.7.15.

Why is that happening and how can I fix it or work around it?

**EDIT: The Solution**

I wasn't thinking straight with naming everything the same. Here was the problem, as it was pointed out in the comments:

On my PC, this is the file structure:

```
OpenNote
    __init__.py
    OpenNoteFlask
        __init__.py
        config.py
```

On my webserver, this is the file structure:

```
OpenNoteFlask
    __init__.py
    OpenNoteFlask
        __init__.py
        config.py
```

The problem ended up being that because I have a package called `OpenNoteFlask` inside a package called `OpenNoteFlask`, the import `from OpenNoteFlask ...` was ambiguous. Python interpreted that import as importing from the parent package and not the subpackage. The solution was to make the two package names different(like on my PC).

Comment: Why do you have a package named `OpenNoteFlask` within a package named `OpenNoteFlask`? That just makes a `import OpenNoteFlask` ambiguous within `OpenNoteFlask`, because it may be relative or absolute. I'm not sure whether that is the cause of the problem, but it sure does not help.

Comment: @zvone Ahh, I see. I don't know what I was thinking. Now that I think about it though, it makes sense that the error is happening. I was able to determine that this is the problem. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @PaoloCastro Please add the solution as a separate answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the imports weren't working was because I was using packages with the same name. You can duplicate this error by doing the following:

```
run.py
package
    __init__.py
    package
        __init__.py
        module.py
```

```py
# run.py
import package

# package/__init__.py
import package

# package/package/__init__.py
from package import module
```

The issue seems to be that when the first `package` is called, python remembers that the first `package` is THE `package`. When the second `package` is called, it searches first in its own directory and finds the second `package` and imports it. On the third import, there isn't another `package` in the directory, so it remembers that THE `package` is the first package and tries to import that. But since the `module.py` file isn't part of the first `package`, the import fails.

The solution is simple: don't have two nested packages with the same name!